# Log the VS debug log to Redis server using Nlog

Tags: c#, redis, nlog

I am using NLog to log the debugging information to Redis server. Which is working fine on Server.
Following is the Nlog.Config file

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="false" autoReload="true">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="App.Host" />
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="Wrapper" name="logstash">
      <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
        <target xsi:type="Redis" host="hostname" key="logstash" dataType="list" port="1234" password="password">
          <layout xsi:type="JsonLayout">
            <attribute name="application" layout="testapplication"/>
            <attribute name="key" layout="value"/>
           
          </layout>
        </target>
      </target>
    </target>
  </targets>
  <rules>
   
    <logger name="Api" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logstash" final="true" />
    
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

logging code is like this

```
Logger apiLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("Api");
apiLogger.Log(infoString);
```

Now I want to have my VS debugging log on the server also, so I have made following changes in NLog.Config file

```
 <logger name="Api" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logstash" final="true" />
```

also changed the C# method to

```
apiLogger.Debug(infoString);
```

but I am not able to see the debug log details on Redis server.
Is there anything more that I need to do?

Comment: Looks fine - Are you sure the updated config file got copied to the output directory?

Comment: JAZ, I am debugging it through visual studio, the above step is still needed?

Comment: The config file needs to be in the bin folder.  In VS, make sure it is set to copy to output directory.  Look in the BIN folder where the exe is and check to see if it is the latest one.

Comment: @JAZ yes its present in bin folder

Comment: Maybe enable [NLog InternalLogger](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging) to see if NLog.config is loaded from the expected location and is parsed correctly. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

I have enabled throwExceptions="true" in following configuration

```
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="false" autoReload="true">
```

Then I started getting exceptions while logging. fixed those issues and it worked